# Loading gif placeholder on:hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/90gkv1gw/

I have an image that loads an animated gif `on:hover`. How can I modify this to show some sort of loading gif placeholder while the animated image takes time to load?

Example: http://giphy.com

If you hover over their images, you briefly see a green animation that slides from left to right, but once the image has fully loaded, it never shows again. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.loading').mouseover(function(e) {
        if (e.target == e.currentTarget){

            var self = $(this),
                loading = self.find('.loadingText'),
                image = $('<img>').attr('src','http://media4.giphy.com/media/fa0ZTUSQu7AjK/200w.gif');

            loading.show();
            image.load(function () { loading.hide(); });

            self.siblings('img').remove();
            self.before(image);
        }

    }).mouseout(function() {
        var self = $(this),
            src = self.siblings('img').attr('src').replace('200w.gif', '200w_s.gif');
        self.siblings('img').attr('src', src);
    });
```

```css
a{
            position:relative;
            width:200px;
            height:150px;
        }
        .loading{
            position:absolute;
            width:200px;
            height:150px;
            top:0;
            left:0;
            text-indent:10px;

        }
        a img{
            position: absolute;
        }
        .loading .loadingText{
            background:red;
            color:white;
            font-size:12px;
            line-height:15px;
            display:none;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#">
    <img src="http://media4.giphy.com/media/fa0ZTUSQu7AjK/200w_s.gif" width="200" />
    <div class="loading">
        <div class="loadingText">Loading</div>
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: This will always bring up `.loading` even after the image has already loaded.

Comment: @OP but the image covers up .loading

Comment: The image is actually cached after the first loading.
The ".loading" div has the same size as the <a> element, with no background. When you move your mouse over it, the message will appear (or you can replace it with a loading.gif image) till the image will be loaded ( If the image is cached, the loading message won't be noticed )

Answer (score 0):

You can use the load function of jQuery

```
$( "#myimage" ).load(function() {

//Put your code here to stop the loading animation
});
```

You can read more here http://api.jquery.com/load-event/